# Multiple domains and one shared session with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, session, cookies, cross-domain

Need: multi-domain session with one single app.

I have at least two domains:

- `mydomain.com`
- `another-domain.net`

All covered by one same Symfony application (I'm using 3.4 at the moment I write this post).

What I need is a way to authenticate once, on any of these websites, via a common form login at a `/login` path and behind a Guard authenticator.

First of all, here is a Gist with some code I'm using: https://gist.github.com/Pierstoval/ca0e9845cfa1118e3d22ea14eb7c8929

Scenario:

1. When I authenticate via the Guard authenticator added to this Gist, I consider that the user **should** authenticate on other websites, so I set a `connect` variable in the session.
2. In the template, if I have this `connect` var in the session, I add this kind of code in the template:

   ```
   window._CONNECT_PATHS = [
       "//mydomain.com/{{ path('connect', {'id': app.session.id}) }}",
       "//another-domain.net/{{ path('connect', {'id': app.session.id}) }}"
   ];
   ```
3. This `_CONNECT_PATHS` var is caught by a JS script that just does a `POST //mydomain(...)` HTTP call using AJAX.
4. This AJAX call is caught by the `EventSubscriber` class added to this Gist, that *"should"* make sure the session is shared.

Is it ok? It seems to work, but sometimes when I authenticate on one website, I have to re-authenticate to the other website. And I cannot figure out when it happens and when it does not.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe because different session id's. Did you check how it works with 20-30 users online? And when i will know session id, can i connect to another service? If yes - this is insecure.  In my opinion, the solution for log-in to multidomain must be an SSO (Single Sign-On). The better way is SAML but it difficult technology.

Comment: Hmm, yes, what I was first thinking is to reset any session with the ID provided at login-time, this is what the AJAX call is for.

Comment: If you're sure it's insecure, I might as well try to find a solution for SSO, but I'll probably need more JS stuff :) But it might allow me to "login with (...)" with my application, if I need more services :) Didn't thought about this, so maybe I'm going to try this, thanks!

Comment: If session id in the browser window - it is insecure. 
Maybe you can use 'oauth'? If yes - check this bundle "hwi/oauth-bundle" connect via the social networks etc.

Comment: I don't want to "log with {external service}", I instead would like all my applications to "log with {my "Connect" app}", so oauth might be an idea.
I'm going to take a look at how SensioLabsConnect work, maybe.

Comment: hey @alex I'm curious about your final solution to this issue, as I'm confronted to the same situation. ( And by the way, your meetup presentation in Montpellier was awesome thanks )

Comment: @db306 I didn't implement this yet. I'm still using the premature solution I have put in this SO issue, but one day I wish to implement a "Connect with {...}" server AND client, but I don't have the time for it and neither have the knowledge for either develop it or implement potential existing bundles/components that may do the job.